# How to use different merge and diff tool in git?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, mergetool, difftool

I prefer to use `meld` as the diff tool. However it doesn't have an option to quickly solve all simple conflicts so in case of merging I'd like to use kdiff3

I've set `merge.tool` to kdiff3 and `diff.guitool` to meld but `git difftool` still always run kdiff3

```ini
[merge]
        tool = kdiff3
        conflictstyle = diff3

[diff]
        guitool = meld
        renames = copies
        mnemonicPrefix = true

[difftool]
        prompt = false
```

How to make `git difftool` run `meld`?

Comment: Don't use kdiff3. It tries to automatically resolve simple conflicts, sometimes completely messing the code without any warning.

Comment: @Claudio really? I didn't kdiff3 so much but it does really help in merging time

Comment: Yes. Once it added my code outside any function, claiming that it automagically had solved the conflict. My next step has been to uninstall the tool. Meld doesn't pretend to be such smart, but at least doesn't mess my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`diff.guitool` only applies if you use the `--gui` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#git-difftool-diffguitool).

Setting `diff.tool` and `merge.tool` should make `git difftool` and `git mergetool` use different tools:

```
[merge]
        tool = kdiff3

[diff]
        tool = meld
```

Answer (score 5):

Note: since Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), the combinations of `{diff,merge}.{tool,guitool}` configuration variables serve as fallback settings of each other in a sensible order.

See [commit 6c22d71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c22d715e7b4067a6865ff3fbceab991d0042c12), [commit 7f978d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f978d7d10a87c4a56ea3101b936cddb25bbe2c6), [commit 60aced3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60aced3dfa68df60952fed28c4ae63a5bbda0275), [commit 884630b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/884630b2e2634969656faabc7f4e33cab2e32b35), [commit 05fb872](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05fb8726cccc74908853c166248ff9b6abdafae5) (29 Apr 2019), and [commit 57d93c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57d93c1d2ce7deddf485e7c826278fef6815ec6b), [commit e9d309e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9d309e2fcd4faaeee9d20ef2a46bf86a4847bd0) (24 Apr 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 85ac27e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85ac27e04fd0cf1d086028e87f69ffb498c1451b), 19 May 2019)</sup>

In your case, since difftool is not defined:

> ### `difftool`: fallback on `merge.guitool`
>
> In git-difftool.txt, it says
>
> > '`git difftool`' falls back to '`git mergetool`' config variables when the
> >         difftool equivalents have not been defined.
>
> However, when `diff.guitool` is missing, it doesn't fallback to
>   anything. Make git-difftool fallback to `merge.guitool` when `diff.guitool` is
>   missing.

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/85ac27e04fd0cf1d086028e87f69ffb498c1451b/Documentation/git-difftool.txt#L88-L95) now includes:

> ### `git difftool -g/--gui`
>
> When '`git difftool`' is invoked with the `-g` or `--gui` option, the default diff tool will be read from the configured `diff.guitool` variable instead of `diff.tool`.
>   The `--no-gui` option can be used to override this setting.
>
> If `diff.guitool` is not set, we will fallback in the order of `merge.guitool`,
>   `diff.tool`, `merge.tool` until a tool is found.