# Git (2.22.0) difftool no longer passes through to git diff if diff.tool is unset

Tags: git, git-difftool

Per @VonC's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56212234 in Git 2.22.0 (released 2019-06-08), a number of changes were made to the `git difftool` command regarding how its configuration is determined.

However, unless I am missing something here, it appears that a regression in functionality has been introduced in this version. In previous versions, including 2.21.0, it has been possible to use `git difftool` without any configuration or CLI options, in which case it passes through to `git diff`.

Now in Git 2.22.0 if I use `git difftool` without configuring `diff.tool` or `merge.tool`, I get the following message:

```
This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
kompare emerge vimdiff
```

Is there any way of bypassing this error and returning to the old behavior of passing through to `git diff` or must I call `git diff` directly?

**edit:** According to Jeff King's [mailing list reply](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190620052125.GA12434@sigill.intra.peff.net/), the new behavior is intentional. However at the top of the [git-difftool documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool), it says that:

> *git difftool* is a frontend to *git diff* and accepts the same options and arguments. See [git-diff[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Is this no longer the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; The new error message "`This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.`" might be an actual bug fix, and *not* a new error.

---

I just tried and... didn't get any error message (when used *without* parameters).

```
vonc@vonvb:~/git/cplgit/linux$ ./set_git 2.22.0
git set to v2.22.0
vonc@vonvb:~/git/cplgit/linux$ git version
git version 2.22.0

vonc@vonvb:~/git/cplgit/linux$ git config -l|grep -i tool

vonc@vonvb:~/git/cplgit/linux$ git difftool
```

Plus, this error message has been introduced in [commit 5338a6a, Jan. 2013, Git v1.8.2-rc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5338a6a924b9519dfbd3c92142f83d6ecf925097).
I did mentioned [commit 05fb872 from Git 2.22](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05fb8726cccc74908853c166248ff9b6abdafae5), which uses `${GIT_MERGETOOL_GUI}`.
That environment variable is not set on my machine, and I don't get any error message.
Check your own `git config` and environment variables.

I do see the error message in Git 2.22 with:

```
vonc@vonvb:~/gits/src/git$ git difftool --no-index color.c color.h

This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
meld opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff kompare gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare smerge emerge vimdiff

Viewing (1/1): 'color.c'
Launch 'bc' [Y/n]? 
The diff tool bc is not available as 'bcompare'
fatal: external diff died, stopping at color.c
```

With Git 2.21.0, it does default to a regular `git diff`:

```
vonc@vonvb:~/git/cplgit/linux$ ./set_git 2.21.0
git set to v2.21.0
vonc@vonvb:~/git/cplgit/linux$ git version
git version 2.21.0
vonc@vonvb:~/git/cplgit/linux$ cdgg
vonc@vonvb:~/gits/src/git$ git difftool --no-index color.c color.h
diff --git a/color.c b/color.h
index ebb222ec33..98894d6a17 100644
```

---

From the [OP Git mailing list thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/SN6PR09MB3248331E45EED2DD26CA55528AE50@SN6PR09MB3248.namprd09.prod.outlook.com/):

**[Denton Liu](https://git.github.io/rev_news/#developer-spotlight-denton-liu)** pinpoints the original [commit 287ab28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/287ab28bfae14431f3f57abeb92149c460044850) (16 Feb 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 12e5bdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12e5bdd9c4bfa0131b00b20be2cc48a8e2b08a2d), 07 Mar 2019)</sup>

> ### `diff`: reuse diff setup for `--no-index` case
>
> When "`--no-index`" is in effect (or implied by the arguments), `git-diff`
>   jumps early to a special code path to perform that diff.
>   This means we miss out on some settings like enabling `--ext-diff` and `--textconv` by default.

[Jeff King replies](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190620052125.GA12434@sigill.intra.peff.net/):

> I don't know much about how `git-difftool` works, but it looks like it
>   sets `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=git-difftool--helper`.
>
> Prior to [287ab28bfa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/287ab28bfae14431f3f57abeb92149c460044850), we would not have respected any external diff
>   command when running `git-diff`. But after it, we do.
>
> **In the case that the user has not provided `--no-index`, then this all
>   works as I guess `difftool` is meant to: it runs the helper and says "hey,
>   you have not configured this".**
>
> It seems like the behavior of the above command prior to [287ab28bfa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/287ab28bfae14431f3f57abeb92149c460044850) was
>   not intentional.
>   It would run `git-diff`, expecting it to trigger the helper, but it never did (and instead just did a normal `no-index diff`).
>
> So it seems like the new behavior is actually the right thing, as it makes the `--no-index` case consistent with the regular one?
>   **I'm not at all clear why you would run "`difftool`" here if you it is not
>   configured and you just want the straight `diff` output.**

Comment: Thank you -- I am not seeing any config/environment variables relating to Git diff/merge tools. What if you do a `git difftool --no-index <file 1> <file 2>`? (ensuring the two files have different contents)

Comment: @blah238 I have edited the answer... which confirms your reported regression. https://github.com/git/git/commit/05fb8726cccc74908853c166248ff9b6abdafae5 is a problem.

Comment: Great thanks for confirming that! Should I send in a bug report to the Git mailing list? Never done that before.

Comment: @blah238 Yes, on https://public-inbox.org/git/. Leave as a comment the URL of your thread on that mailing list.

Comment: @blah238 Just checked with Git 2.23.0 batch 2: the error does persists.

Comment: thanks for checking that. I submitted the report here: https://public-inbox.org/git/SN6PR09MB3248331E45EED2DD26CA55528AE50@SN6PR09MB3248.namprd09.prod.outlook.com/

Comment: @blah238 I have edited the answer to reflect the current conclusion of the thread.

Comment: I am not able to easily reply to the mailing list but I agree with their conclusion. Apparently I was relying on a bug instead of a feature without knowing it.